# I am unable to migrate in my django project

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, migrate

I have connected my django project with mysql database and i have configured all my settings(settings.py), but when migrate ,it shows the error.

[image: Source code]

Comment: Add your database setting code to your question.

Comment: Please fix the host name ' localhost'.

Answer (score 0):

In your database description you have defined your database as ' localhost' not 'localhost'. Django will not fix the whitespace for you in the settings file.